# What is the use of logical(), double(), etc. as default argument value

Tags: r, function, arguments

**Rewritten after @G. Grothendieck's answer**

In *Advanced R*, about [S3 classes](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/s3.html#s3-constructor), I came across the following function definition :

```
new_Date <- function(x = double()) {
  stopifnot(is.double(x))
  structure(x, class = "Date")
}
```

I thought giving `double()` as default value was a way of coercing the user to enter a `double` value for `x` type, but it appears it is not since the function checks afterwards with `stopifnot`.

Reading @G. Grothendieck's answer, I understand that `double()` is a *double NA*. Does this mean that the usage of `double()` is only to allow the function to work with an (empty) double even when no argument is provided (rather than throwing the *missing argument* error), and has nothing to do with checking on x's class ?

**Original question**

I sometimes see functions defined with default values for arguments as an empty (or fixed-length) type, as such :

```
func1 <- function(a = logical(), b = numeric(1)){
    if (a){
        b
    } else {
        0
    }
}
```

I understand that it simplifies reading to know what type of each argument is. But it does not appear to force the argument to be this type.

```
func1(a = 4, b = 3)
# 3
func1(a = 4, b = TRUE)
# TRUE
```

I know that if, in that specific example, I change `if (a)` into `if (a == TRUE)`, it will trigger an error if `a` is not a logical. But in general, if there is no checking on arguments' type inside the function's body, what is the use of this type of argument definition ?

I would tend to prefer that kind of function definition, but it is far heavier :

```
func2 <- function(a, b){
    if (class(a) != 'logical') stop('a must be logical')
    if (!(class(b) == 'numeric' & length(b) == 1)) stop(
        'b must be numeric(1)'
    )
    ...
}
```

Comment: Probably hard to answer a "why" question like this without a specific example of such a function, rather than a constructed hypothetical.

Comment: You're right, I know remember that I saw these forms in the classes section of *Advanced R* (https://adv-r.hadley.nz/s3.html#s3-constructor), and didn't understand the need to write `function(x = double())` when there is a type check afterward `stopifnot(is.double(x))`. Should I edit the question with this example even now there is an answer to it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### stopifnot

Assuming that if `a` is a logical NA then it should still return 0 then try this (or replace the second line of the body with `a * b` if a logical NA for `a` should return NA).

At any rate the main point is that the following `stopifnot` style can be used for argument checking.

```
func2 <- function(a, b) {
  stopifnot(is.logical(a), is.numeric(b))
  isTRUE(a) * b
}

func2(TRUE, 3)
## [1] 3

func2(9, 2)
## Error in func2(9, 2) : is.logical(a) is not TRUE
```

Instead of `stopifnot` use `if (...) stop(...)`, one such statement per argument, if you want custom error messages.

### S3 and S4

Note that it is possible to use S3 to dispatch to a method based on the first argument or S4 to dispatch to a given signature.  If a method for such a signature does not exist an error will be triggered.

Here is an S4 example:

```
setMethod("func3", c("logical", "numeric"), function(a, b) isTRUE(a) * b)

func4(TRUE, 3)
## [1] 3

func4(2, 1)
## Error in UseMethod("func3") : 
##  no applicable method for 'func4' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"
```

Here is an S3 example:

```
# check 1st arg using S3 dispatch and 2nd arg using stopifnot
func3 <- function(a, b) UseMethod("func4")
func3.logical <- function(a, b) {
  stopifnot(is.numeric(b))
  isTRUE(a) * b
}

func3(TRUE, 3)
## [1] 3

func3(3, 8)
## Error in UseMethod("func3") : 
##  no applicable method for 'func3' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"
```

### Other

There is a package on CRAN called [checkmate](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/checkmate/index.html) for argument checking that is used by quite a few other packages (replacing the now defunct [ArgumentCheck](https://cran.r-project.org/package=ArgumentCheck) package).  Another package for type checking of arguments is [TypeInfo](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/TypeInfo.html) on Bioconductor.

There is a package called [rtype](https://cran.r-project.org/package=rtype) for strong type checking.

Also there are packages [assertive.types](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/assertive.types/index.html), [assertive](https://cran.r-project.org/package=assertive), [assertr](https://cran.r-project.org/package=assertr), [assertable](https://cran.r-project.org/package=assertable) and [assertthat](https://cran.r-project.org/package=assertthat) for type assertions.

Also note that regarding the code in the question that an S3 class is a vector and so can have more than one element so use `is.someclass` (if such a function exists for `someclass`) or `inherits(X, "someclass")` where `someclass` is the class of interest rather than `class(X) == "someclass"`  for checking S3 classes.

Comment: S3 context was indeed where I saw these forms (see my question to @joran's comment in my question), can I edit my question with a true example from *Advanced R* ?

Comment: If that would change the question after the answers have already b3een given then it is not really the best course but if it just clarifies the question rather than changing it then there would be no harm.

Comment: Ok I did edit it but let the original question, feel free to tell me if the whole does not make sense any more